# firefox addon: create a new thread and dispatch nsIRunnable to it?

Tags: multithreading, firefox, firefox-addon

Why does this crash FireFox? Copy and paste this code into the browser console (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd>):

```
function TestRunner(){}
TestRunner.prototype={
    classDescription:"TestRunner",
    classID:Components.ID("{09AA3487-7531-438D-B0B2-80BC24B584C0}"),
    contractID:"@yoy.be/TestRunner;1",
    QueryInterface:XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIRunnable]),
    run:function(){
        console.log("ping");
    }
};
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"].getService().newThread(0).dispatch(new TestRunner(),0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Firefox 4(-ish) the whole Javascript engine became far less thread safe, to the extend where e.g. simple things such as just "reading" a string concurrently may cause memory corruption (because these reads might actually materialize strings views for string ropes).

Therefore it was decided that dispatching javascript-implemented `nsIRunnable` isn't supported anymore as there is no safe way to use it, and people should switch over to [ChromeWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChromeWorker) where possible.

*Edit* You said in the comments that you wanted to implement `nsIChannel`/`nsIProtocolHandler`. AFAIK you can implement nsIProtocolHandler and nsIChannel without any threads and binaries. If you still have to have threads and/or binaries, then your Javascript XPCOM (stub) components would "simply" communicate with a ChromeWorker via message passing (pass around ArrayBuffers/typed arrays; those are zero-copy). The ChromeWorker would then do any heavy lifting, incl. any [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) calls to interface with binaries.

Comment: Ah yes, ChomeWorkers. I thought of using a ChromeWorker to do the ctypes work with, but couldn't get this to work, so I'm now thinking about using nsIFileInputStream on a named pipe and have a nsIInputStreamPump handle it async...

Comment: If you're after async File I/O have a look at [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File) and/or [Wladimir's old writeup](https://adblockplus.org/blog/using-asynchronous-file-i-o-in-gecko). Also, for smallish files, async XHR with a file:/chrome: URI might be enough.

Comment: Seems I missed the named pipe bit :p. Without knowing what you're trying to eventually do, I don't think you can expect any more advice. Please post proper questions e.g. regarding your ctypes issues. Anyway, the OS.File implementation does use ctypes (and array buffers for non-copy data transfers between threads) so maybe have a [peak](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/osfile/modules/)...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is implement nsIProtocolHandler and nsIChannel. In the old binary days, I just kept a pointer to the current thread my asyncOpen was called on, and dispatched my nsIRunnable's on it to have them call OnDataAvailable and others on the listener. (in case you're interested, the code is here http://sourceforge.net/p/xxm/code/312/tree/trunk/Delphi/gecko/xxmGeckoChannel.pas )

Comment: I added a few words regarding `nsIChannel` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run non-XPCOM JavaScript on other threads using (chrome) workers, and you can dispatch C++ implementations of nsIRunnable to other threads, but you can only use XPConnect on the main thread. This is because XPConnect objects could be cycle-collected and the cycle collector isn't threadsafe.

Comment: C++ implementations of nsIRunnable? Interesting, is there a way to get to them using js-ctypes (since I'm kind-of trying to avoid the XPCOM binary component registration)?

Comment: There is no *sane* way, nope. And as you already found out, XPCOM binary components in add-on suck and should be avoided.